# Picasso not loading big images

Tags: android, image, picasso

I am using the library `Picasso` to download images. For small images it is working great, but for 1.5Mb images or more the method `onBitmapFailed` is called and the image is not displayed. This is how I do it:

```
final int shortestSide = Math.min(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth());

final int longestSideView = Math.max(getAvailableHeight(), getAvailableWidth());
final float picassoScale = (float) longestSideView / (float) shortestSide;

final int widthWithoutExif;
final int heightWithoutExif;

final int exifRotation = Util.mod(image.getExifOrientation(), 360);
    switch (exifRotation){
        case 90:
        case 270:
            widthWithoutExif = image.getHeight();
            heightWithoutExif = image.getWidth();

            break;
        default:
            widthWithoutExif = image.getWidth();
            heightWithoutExif = image.getHeight();
    }

final RequestCreator requestCreator;
requestCreator = picasso.load(new File(cacheFilePath()));
requestCreator.resize((int) (widthWithoutExif * picassoScale), (int) (heightWithoutExif * picassoScale));
requestCreator.into(this);
```

Does someone know what I am missing? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
This is the stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot reset
04-25 14:20:30.225 26278-26278/debug W/System.err:     at        com.squareup.picasso.MarkableInputStream.reset(MarkableInputStream.java:99)
04-25 14:20:30.225 26278-26278/debug W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.decodeStream(BitmapHunter.java:140)
04-25 14:20:30.225 26278-26278/debug W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:217)
04-25 14:20:30.225 26278-26278/debug W/System.err:     at    com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
04-25 14:20:30.225 26278-26278/debug W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
04-25 14:20:30.225 26278-26278/debug W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-25 14:20:30.225 26278-26278/debug W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-25 14:20:30.225 26278-26278/debug W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-25 14:20:30.225 26278-26278/debug W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-25 14:20:30.225 26278-26278/debug W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
```

Comment: Set up [a `listener()`](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/index.html?com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.Builder.html) to get the exception information about the failure.

Comment: I have already tried it and I get MemoryOutException, I will edit my question, sorry I forgot about that

Comment: The resolution of the used image is too high. Use images with less pixels. Or scale more.

Comment: Post the entire Java stack trace of the exception. My guess is that you are running out of memory when doing the rotation. Rather than rotate the image, rotate the `ImageView` (or whatever `this` is).

Comment: I was wrong, the exception is: IOException: Cannot reset

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found that this is a `Picasso` bug. The [link](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/364) to the issue. It is fixed by upgrading to 2.5.3-SNAPSHOT.